# How do you handle dynamic column names in a SwiftUI Table on Mac

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI table that I need to layout based on some request data from a server. This data is dynamic and changes. However, once I read this data into an array, it will not allow me to do a forEach on the column data, as it companies about not conforming to "TableColumnContent". Is there another way to loop this creation, or is there a simple way to conform to this protocol? I am having trouble understanding that protocol when I look at it.

```
struct DataProperty : Identifiable
{
    var id: String
    var name: String
}

struct TableDataView : View
{
    @EnvironmentObject var cache: ServerCache
    
    var body: some View
    {
        Table(cache.activeTableData)
        {
            ForEach(cache.activeProperties, id: \.self) {property in
                
                TableColumn(property.name, value: \.id)
                
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Note that activeProperties is an array of DataProperty. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are asking but normally you do something like `TableColumn("Header", value: \.id)` or `TableColumn("Header") { Text(property.name)}`

Comment: @JoakimDanielson - Yes,  I know how to define the headers explicitly. Its when I go to do it dynamically off of the array of data where I get hung up due to the data structure needing to conform to TableColumnContent

Comment: If you mean dynamic number of columns then it is not supported for now by `Table` - there is no init with ForEachColumns, only via builder, it means up to 10 columns

Comment: @Asperi - Ok, so just to be clear, what I am trying to do with the columns being created dynamically is impossible, and even if I did explicitly list the columns, it would only take 10 max? Seems super limiting. I was going to have upward of 30 in many places.

Comment: Did you try LazyVGrid which seems more appropriate ?

Comment: @PtitXav - Yes I am using that now, but it certainly isn't as nicely formatted without more work. It seems like a very big shortcoming from a control point of view to not support dynamic data.

Comment: Very limiting indeed–running into this as well right now. Enabling the user to change the name of a column header does not seem to be possible with `Table`–will have to see if `LazyVGrid` would solve this for me...

Comment: Seems to be it's supported in future: TableColumnForEach https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/tablecolumnforeach