# SwiftUI Table - dynamic columns

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I am fairly new to swift and swiftui, trying to build a csv reader macOS application.

I was just wondering if there is a way to render a SwiftUI Table with dynamic Columns - there is no was to know the number of columns at build time.

I can't find any resource about this.

I have tried the following structure but it doesn't work, as the columns aren't hardcoded.

```
Table(viewModel.rows, selection: $selection) {
    ForEach(viewModel.columns, id: \.self) { column in
        TableColumn(column, value: { row in
            Text(row[column] as? String ?? "")
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem possible right now. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71860582/how-do-you-handle-dynamic-column-names-in-a-swiftui-table-on-mac

Answer (score 1):

Apparently it is now possible. Have not tested myself, but the latest apple sdks include:

[TableColumnBuilder](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/tablecolumnbuilder) and
[TableColumnForEach](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/tablecolumnforeach)